# An integral related to the Euler gamma function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, open-problems

The question is from the paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7115 (A curious formula related to the Euler Gamma function, by Bakir Farhi): is it possible to express the integral
$$\eta=2\int\limits_0^1 \ln{(\Gamma(x))}\cdot \sin{(2\pi x)}\,dx=        0.7687478924\ldots$$
in terms of the known mathematical constants as $\pi,\,e,\,\gamma,\;\ln{\pi},\,
\ln{2},\,\Gamma{(1/4)}\ldots$? It is shown in the paper that 
$$\frac{\ln{1}}{1}-\frac{\ln{3}}{3}+\frac{\ln{5}}{5}-\ldots=\pi\ln{(\Gamma{(1/4)})}-\frac{\pi^2}{4}\eta-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\pi}-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln{2}.$$ So the question actually asks whether one can give a closed-form expression for the series in the l.h.s. in terms of the known mathematical constants.

Comment: Here there is a good historical review on Euler Gamma function,http://sgpwe.izt.uam.mx/files/users/uami/jdf/proyectos/Euler_integral.pdf. In this thesis you can find a lot of relation about your question http://siva.cc.hirosaki-u.ac.jp/usr/mnishi/thesis.pdf

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's introduce a notation

$$\alpha_k := \intop_0^1 \sin(2 \pi k z) \log \Gamma(z) dz$$

Let me also remind of the duplication formula:

$$\log \Gamma(2z) = \log \Gamma(z) + \log \Gamma(z + 1/2) + 2\log 2 \cdot z - \log(2 \sqrt \pi)$$

Now apply that to the calculation of $\alpha_k$:

$$\alpha_k = 2 \intop_0^{1/2} \sin(4 \pi k z) \log \Gamma(2z) dz =$$
$$= 2 \intop_0^{1/2} \sin(4 \pi k z) (\log \Gamma(z) + \log \Gamma(z + 1/2)) dz + 4 \log 2 \cdot \intop_0^{1/2} z \sin(4 \pi k z) dz =$$
$$= 2 \alpha_{2k} - \frac{\log 2} {2 \pi k}$$

In particular, this implies that $\alpha_1 = 2^n \alpha_{2^n} - \frac{\log 2}{2 \pi} \cdot n$. The limit of that as $n \to \infty$ can be calculated, at least in principle, since this kind of asymptotics of Fourier coefficients depends only on the point where the function has a singularity, which is the endpoint here. The singularity here comes from the $\log$ term in expansion $\Gamma(z) = -\log z - \gamma z + \dots$ at zero, so the asymptotics of Fourier coefficients must be the same as that of $-\log$ (up to lower order terms that are irrelevant).

So we can relate to a constant that, I presume, must be better known by

$$ \intop_0^1 \sin(2 \pi k z) \log z^{-1} dz = \frac{1}{2\pi} k^{-1} \log k + \frac{1}{2} \eta k^{-1} + \dots $$

**Upd.** That, in turn, may be expressed in terms of the cosine integral:

$$ \intop_0^1 \sin(2 \pi k z) \log z^{-1} dz = \frac{1}{2 \pi k} \intop_0^{2 \pi k} (1 - \cos z) z^{-1} dz =$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2 \pi k} (\log k + \gamma + \log (2 \pi) - \mathrm {Ci}(2 \pi k))$$

Since $\mathrm{Ci}(x) = O(x^{-1})$ at $+\infty$, we have

$$\eta = \frac{\gamma + \log (2 \pi)}{\pi}$$

Answer (score 8):

Experimentally with mpmath this holds to precision $1000$ decimal
digits:

$$
\frac{\ln{1}}{1}-\frac{\ln{3}}{3}+\frac{\ln{5}}{5}-\ldots =
-1/4\,\pi \, \left( \gamma+2\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) +3\,\ln  \left( \pi  \right) -4\,\ln  \left( {\frac {\pi \,\sqrt {2}}{\Gamma  \left( 3 /4 \right) }} \right)  \right) $$

and

$$
\eta = {\frac {\gamma+\ln  \left( 2 \right) +\ln  \left( \pi  \right) }{\pi }}
$$

Program:

```
import mpmath
from mpmath import pi,gamma,euler,log
pre=100 #precision, adjust
mpmath.mp.dps=pre
mpmath.mp.pretty=True
A=mpmath.nsum(lambda n: (-1)**n*log(2*n+1)/(2*n+1) ,[0,mpmath.inf])
B= -(pi/4)*(euler+2*log(2)+3*log(pi)-4*log(gamma(1/4)))
print mpmath.chop(A-B)
```

Comment: The displayed equation has a more complicated expression in place of the $\Gamma(1/4)$ that appears in the code.  Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @S.Carnahan Indeed. This was produced by latex() in Maple, don't know why...

Comment: According to Euler's reflection formula $\Gamma(1-1/4)\Gamma(1/4)=\frac{\pi}{\sin{\pi/4}}=\sqrt{2}\pi$. So $\Gamma(3/4)$ can be expressed through $\Gamma(1/4)$. If I didn't make a mistake in a hurry, joro's result implies $\eta=(\gamma+\ln{2}+\ln{\pi}+8\ln{(\Gamma(1/4))}$.

Comment: @ZurabSilagadze I edited the answer with different result for eta which holds at least to 1000 decimal digits. It doesn't depend on $\Gamma$.

Comment: $\eta = \frac{\gamma + \log(2 \pi)}{\pi}$. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @AlexanderShamov this is the same as the experimental after expanding your log().

Comment: Your experimental data suggests that the mistakes in my calculation cancel each other. :)

Comment: @joro How did you find the answer? Yes $\Gamma$ cancels out, I made a mistake.

Comment: @ZurabSilagadze found it with Inverse Symbolic Calculator, this one:  http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advanced

Answer (score 2):

In fact, both the experimental result by Joro and the (very nice) asymptotic analysis by A. Shamov, above, are correct. I'd like to advice those more interested readers that I've included this topic and some generalizations in my most recent work on integrals and series involving the log-Gamma function (to appear in arXiv website). F. M. S. Lima

Comment: The paper by F.M.S. Lima, mentioned above, was submitted to "Ramanujan Journal" one year ago. He has sent me a PDF copy and explained that he is waiting for acceptance before sending a copy to arXiv.

Comment: With respect to my paper, I was only waiting for a (delayed) Referee report. My paper has been posted on arXiv. https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.04303